# Как настроить KeyEvent Android

Tags: java, android, клавиатура, key

Хочу в приложении сделать поддержку некоторых спец клавиш (F1, F2, F3...), поскольку имееца планшет с физ.клавиатурой..
Вопрос как это сделать?
Можно материал по теме?
За пример кода буду очень благодарен...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Материал по теме всегда есть в официальной [документации](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/commands.html#ModifierKey). Клас [KeyEvent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html) для событий нажатия на клавишу имеет константы для F1, F2, ... . Небольшой пример для вашего случая:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_F1:
            //F1 pressed
            return true;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_F2:
            //F2 pressed
            return true;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_F3:
            //F3 pressed
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Для реализации метода `onKeyUp` вы должны в вашей `Activity` или `View` имплементировать интерфейс [`KeyEvent.Callback`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.Callback.html).